# Make buffer-menu open in a new, temporary window

Tags: emacs, buffer, elisp

Is there a way to customize the behavior of `buffer-menu` such that it mimics the `list-buffers` command?

What I'm really after is making `buffer-menu` open in a new Emacs window, and after selecting the desired buffer, the `buffer-menu` window closes, and the previous window switches to the selected buffer.

I've looked at various solutions, such as `ibuffer`, and I've tried writing Elisp to do it, but I'm having trouble getting the user selection from the menu buffer. Is there a way to get that value? Or, is there a way to wait until the user has made a selection in `menu-buffer`, either via the keyboard or a mouse click?

Comment: What's the purpose of splitting the window in this scenario? (As you want the current window to end up un-split and containing the selected buffer, the default behaviour of `buffer-menu` and `ibuffer` seems ideal to me.)

Comment: Maybe, you should use `list-buffers` and select the buffers with the key `1`. Then the selected buffer is shown in a single window frame.

Comment: I posted your answer-in-question as a separate answer so that it shows up as an answer to future visitors. You're welcome to post it as an answer of your own and earn reputation from it, just comment on my answer if you do this and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to customize 'buffer-menu'

All Emacs extension and customization mechanisms could be used. For example you could define a function called `buffer-menu-other-frame` on the same basis as it exists a `buffer-menu-other-window` :

```
(defun buffer-menu-other-frame (&optional arg)
  "Display the Buffer Menu in another frame.
See `buffer-menu' for a description of the Buffer Menu.

By default, all buffers are listed except those whose names start
with a space (which are for internal use).  With prefix argument
ARG, show only buffers that are visiting files."
  (interactive "P")
  (switch-to-buffer-other-frame (list-buffers-noselect arg))
  (message
   "Commands: d, s, x, u; f, o, 1, 2, m, v; ~, %%; q to quit; ? for help."))
```

Then you could define a macro to do what you want when you press <kbd>RET</kbd>. Then associate this macro to <kbd>RET</kbd> in `buffer-menu-mode`.

Comment: This was very close and led me to the solution. I've was able to use switch-to-buffer-other-window and have added two define-keys to Buffer-menu-mode-map to get the behavior I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*[The text of this answer was originally written by [irrelephant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3011062/irrelephant)]*

I was able to use `buffer-menu-other-window` to split the frame and get the desired behavior by using the following bindings:

```
(define-key Buffer-menu-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'Buffer-menu-1-window)
(define-key Buffer-menu-mode-map [mouse-2] 'Buffer-menu-1-window)
```

Although the above works fine if you're only using one window, it breaks when you try it and you're already using a split window. In that case, it takes some further tweaking:

```
(defun my-buffer-menu (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (split-window-below)
  (other-window 1)
  (buffer-menu))

(defun my-buffer-menu-1-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((target-buffer (Buffer-menu-buffer t)))
    (delete-window)
    (switch-to-buffer target-buffer)))

(define-key Buffer-menu-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'my-buffer-menu-1-window)
(define-key Buffer-menu-mode-map [mouse-2] 'my-buffer-menu-1-window)
```